# Wanting a key press to be read automatically by console

Tags: vb.net, console

I have the following code, What I want to do is for the console to read the key-press and store this in a variable, like a `Console.ReadLine` but without the need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the line.

```
Dim Player As charStats
    Console.WriteLine("In order to create your character, You must first choose a name for your Character")
    Console.WriteLine("Is your character Male or Female? (M/F)")
    Dim mOrF As String = Console.ReadLine().ToLower
```

Comment: The code is not part of the question. Please include it...

Comment: Do include your codes.. Btw you have the KeyPress() event!

Comment: Code added to the OP

Answer (score 1):

At a guess `Console.ReadKey()` is what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx